# why is type checker considering this as a wrong type and how to deal with that?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a problem with the typescript type checker. I defined the following types and type guard:

```js
type Result = ResultFail | ResultSuccess;

type ResultSuccess = {
  data: unknown;
  success: true
};

type ResultFail = {
  data: Record<string, never>;
  success: false;
}

const isResultFail = (subject: Result): subject is ResultFail =>
  !subject.success

type A =
  | ASuccess
  | AFail;

type ASuccess =
  ABase & {
    result: ResultSuccess;
  };

type AFail =
  ABase & {
    result: ResultFail;
  };

type ABase = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};
```

I am trying to write the function that build `A`. When I am doing it like this it is not working:

```js
const buildA = (result: Result): A => {
  return {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    result,
  }
}
```

But when I am doing it the other way it works:

```js
const buildA = (result: Result): A => {
  if (isResultFail(result)) {
    return {
      result,
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }
  }
  return {
      result,
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why first version does not work, but the second does. I am really confused about it.

Comment: Type `{x: number; y: number;} & ({result: ResultSuccess} | {result: ResultFail});` (`A`) is not the same as type `{x: number; y: number; result: ResultSuccess | ResultFail; }` (what your first function is returning). That's why your version with the type guard works, because it either returns type `{x: number; y: number; result: ResultSuccess; }` **or** type `{x: number; y: number; result: ResultFail; }`, not `{x: number; y: number;} & ({result: ResultSuccess} | {result: ResultFail});`. But I can't give you a deep reason why.

Comment: It is "the same type" if you view types as corresponding to sets of values; you'd be hard pressed to find a value of type `{result: ResultSuccess} | {result: ResultFail}` which is not also a value of type `{result: Result}`, and vice versa.  But the compiler cannot generally verify that two given types are the same if their structure differs; there are some situations where it does do that (discriminated unions of small numbers of members) but this is not one of them (`{result: ResultSuccess} | {result: ResultFail}` would be a "nested" discriminated union, but that's not supported by TS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler compares a type `X` to see if is assignable to another type `Y`, it unfortunately cannot spend too much time checking.  If they have different apparent structure, the assignment might be rejected even if every valid value of type `X` is also a valid value of type `Y`.  One such situation where presumably valid assignments get rejected is when you try to assign unions of objects with properties like `{a: string} | {a: number}` to objects with unions of proprerties like `{a: string | number}`:

```
declare let x: { a: string } | { a: number }
declare let y: { a: string | number };
x = y; // error
```

In order to validate this assignment, the compiler would need to split apart `{a: string | number}` into `{a: string} | {a: number}`.  While this wouldn't be so bad, the general procedure would be very unwieldy.  Imagine the compiler is given `{a: string | number | symbol, b: Date | RegExp | string[], c: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6}` and needs to test against some union of object types.  It would need to produce a union of 3×3×6 = 54 members, and similar unions elsewhere would lead to an explosion of types for the compiler to check.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) and related issues for more information, and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45230#issuecomment-889251512) on microsoft/TypeScript#45230 for an authoritative statement about why this can't be done in general.

---

Before TypeScript 3.5, such assignments always failed.  But TypeScript 3.5 introduced support for ["smarter" union type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779).  Now, if your union-of-object-types is a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and some other criteria are met, the assignment can succeed:

```
declare let x: { a: 0, z: 2 | 3 } | { a: 1, z: 3 | 4 }
declare let y: { a: 0 | 1, z: 3 };
x = y; // okay
```

This works because the type of `x` is a discriminated union with `a` as the discriminant property.  The [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `0` and `1` can be used to determine which member of the union you're in.  And so the above assignment works since TypeScript 3.5.

So, hooray.

---

Unfortunately for you, the union type you have is *not* a discriminated union.  Your would-be discriminant property is not a literal type, but an object type which is *itself* a discriminated union.

```
declare let x: { a: { d: 0 }, z: 2 | 3 } | { a: { d: 1 }, z: 3 | 4 }
declare let y: { a: { d: 0 } | { d: 1 }, z: 3 };
x = y; // error
```

That is, your union type is something like a "nested discriminated union".  And TypeScript does not support these.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) for a feature request asking for such support.

Just to be clear, this is what you're trying to do:

```
declare let x:
  { result: ResultSuccess, x: number, y: number } |
  { result: ResultFail, x: number, y: number };
declare let y: { result: Result, x: number, y: number };
x = y; // error
```

And this fails because the `result` property is not seen as a discriminant of a discriminated union.  Oh well.

---

Your other approach works because you use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow what I'm calling `y` to either the left or the right leg of the union of `x`, and now there is no union propagation to worry about:

```
declare let x:
  { result: ResultSuccess, x: number, y: number } |
  { result: ResultFail, x: number, y: number };
declare let y1: { result: ResultSuccess, x: number, y: number };
declare let y2: { result: ResultFail, x: number, y: number };
x = y1; // okay
x = y2; // okay
```

If you're okay with this approach, and you're willing to sacrifice convenience for type safety, great.  Otherwise, since this is just a design limitation of TypeScript, my suggestion here is probably for you to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on with your life.  You know more than the compiler here about the safety of your code, so you can just tell it so:

```
const buildA = (result: Result) => {
  return {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    result,
  } as A; // assert here
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeWCXAGIEMBLZKAHyyVQGVEBjWheAbgCgXRIKcb7GMoA3iyhQAJvmD4AXFEQA7ANZyA9gHc5rEUl7x4M4ACdEEFgF9W7cNDiU8REpiEjxkmXFrKDogDzxDhOQBzABooOQgANwgDAD5NKG0GXRkAM3xkeAhWUzYPOT8oQngbHAJifgAKJAAjACsIWmA3bFQAShka+sbC+C5UMocY4SgAQk6G4AA6RMY2DmgAQQxh8gWeJPgVqAWBi3nt9b50YYWAIXxMqAAyQWGRAxamvuBD3XjzOattgeWRM4voDcnCIoA9bM1bLthh9LJx-pdHMMAB4yOSIAC21Wi8RAqIxWIM2QsLDyBWqiGIoiWmAqYJwEJw7W2GBit3uEGAiAMcjZIJRUAAjME7lBcYLhSDQY8JVAcjkScp8mhyZSFgAmSp01AMtoyams4GEFJQCpFEr9ey0x6tVq89mc7l2kFa4AyyX8oUikRiz2SnIif1Sh084Hs2xuqAeiM+mVythyfDohBgfAMKAAVTkhEV51EvNEDWQ+AeUGQHMjMgEUGkCX8QVlZEE1bxmOisuGBdoRZLZbQYqrNb8BgCgUbaNbBll8SR-BATCgAHoF1BogZPGY2CwE0n4Cm0wARIq0YfozPZuQAcWUyjzwM73egvYrTZrAAZQgAvGQa8gAZgb5ADjIQpQF+UD-uQAAs7bOIWxaPuW-bNlAr6NiBYH-h8Igzpgc6LsuygKPgIAbluibJqm0AAHIIMAECiIe8DHoQp5Zjm+C3h2cE9uW-JAU2ogyKhpift+jaYY2-FVoJgqyqJ4GNtBgb3vBpaIZWyHSUJAECcBcmgTImHTrO85LiuBhrgYpHbhRaZUJAyBlqIADyiBoHe3EIWgKIilWLo6i8dAbKE-LjgSoRimFbamGQvlSuCzwDCFLbhaKKXRfEKk8X2Gn+c8yVhPi0QRelk5YZGJn4eZlmkWRO57tAzlESAACSKT2cghDuVxXaqU+PmSn5jwBa88AFVFBglYVE4AXFeXmnYxDjUVk1pdNBJTj1D5qX2Aq5cNzyjctE5TRNm2wb12Wimq+0JQtSXPhNp0redFW4QKpkEc1yKzmqn1QIRxFsPKpLKhSyBUgsujRGgNLzdaLK8g8wZOlGIoxiKLqxtWvQLP9FyZAYaAABbRCYORAA)